# How to input/output Google Dataflow with SFTP

Tags: sftp, google-cloud-dataflow

In the demo, the source use the google storage. 
But how to replace it with SFTP?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use pysftp to download your data and save it into GCS bucket outside your beam pipeline. And then start the beam pipeline pointing the GCS bucket. Since your workflow in batch by nature, so that would do. There is not FTP connector in beam.